# List of apex datatypes

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex, sqldatatypes

I'm self-learning about oracle apex and am wanting to find a list of datatypes I can use. I know about a few, for example, char, varchar2, number. I have done some quick searching of the documentation and google with no success apart from the generic sql datatypes which don't seem to match up to what I can use in apex. Does anybody have a list/ link to details in the documentation or know where i can find one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really any such thing as an "apex datatype" - Oracle Application Express is a web application development tool built with Oracle PL/SQL, so it can be made to work (in various ways) with any datatype supported by Oracle SQL or PL/SQL.

In one sense, Apex only has one datatype - a VARCHAR2 string. Any number or date when bound to an Apex item will be converted (explicitly or implicitly) to a string.